# How come this Node.js plugin, Mongoose, doesn't work? I followed all instructions

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/guesswho');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Message = new Schema({
    author: { type:String },
    body: { type:String },
});
var MessageModel = mongoose.model("Message");
```

I followed every instruction here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose

But I get this error when run: `Error: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Message".`

I even tried this: `var MessageModel = mongoose.model("Message", Message);`
When I do this...there is no error. However, MessageModel is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed:

```
var Message = new Schema({
    author: { type:String },
    body: { type:String },
});
mongoose.model("Message",Message);
var MessageModel = mongoose.model("Message");
var aMessage = new MessageModel();
aMessage.author = "apple";
aMessage.body = "orange";
aMessage.save(function(e){

});
```

Someone from IRC called coreb fixed it.

Comment: Yea you created the schema but you never saved it. so when you were trying to get it, it couldn't find it.

Comment: upvote for same reason. And it actually saved me sometime finding an subtile error.